# laravel email notification not send by cron job

Tags: laravel, email, notifications

i am sending a notification via email (smtp) and database. something like [this link](https://rafaelogic.medium.com/use-laravel-notifications-and-schedule-to-send-email-notification-a1a4c652a816).

when call the command from route by calling directly:

**`Artisan::call('notification:unreadmessages')`**

it send an email and insert to notification table, while when call it from cron job or ssh run:

**`php artisan notification:unreadmessages`**

**it doesn't send the email just add record to database notification table.**

i don't know how to debug this why not send email in case of command line or cron job, knowing that while debug in all cases the code enter on "`toMail`" method

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understandt; these are 2 different commands. And do you add `php artisan my_notification:check` directly as your scheduled command to cron? Why you don't use Laravel Task Scheduling: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling ? And are you using queue to send notifications?

Comment: When copy/paste here i keep old commands but both are the same i edit the post above. Yes i try also using schedule in kernel.php file but the same result as calling the command from ssh only insert to db but not sending the email

Comment: Yes i try to add a cron job which call the schedule and in kernel like $schedule->command('notification:unreadmessages')->daily(); it run and add to table notification in database but not sending email. Also when artisan call the command not sending the email. Only send email in case if i add a route and inside i call Artisan::call('notification:unreadmessages') then it send email.